# adding leaders using html or style sheets

Tags: html, stylesheet

Is there any way to fill a style sheet box with leader?

For example given two style sheet boxes next to each other...

```
Topic                                         132
```

I'd like to fill the first box with . . . on the right so it looks like

```
Topic . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 132
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's a page with some options.](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Dot_Leaders) Looks like a simple repeating image is one of your only options. [This page](http://fu2k.org/alex/css/test/DotLeaderRiff.mhtml) has an example.

Comment: This works fine but it's somewhat unsatisfying to say where I don't want leaders rather than where I do want them.  I've successfully added leaders using the pseudo tag 'after' and the 'content' tag.  This also eliminates the need for another external file.  If anyone wants to see the css, let me know.